# C# IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, geometry

At runtime the program says an index is out of range, but I don't know why.

The line that the error messager points out is

`Points[counter + ((int)(radius * 100))].X = i;`

If that one has an error, the next one (with the same index) must also have an error.

`Points[counter + ((int)(radius * 100))].Y = (Points[counter].Y * -1);`

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Circle circle = new Circle(new Point2D(30F, 30F), 10F);
            foreach (Point2D point in circle.Points)
            {
                Console.Write(point.X + " = X\n" + point.Y + " = Y");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }

    public struct Point2D
    {
        public float X;
        public float Y;

        public Point2D(float x, float y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
    }

    class Circle
    {
        public Point2D[] Points;
        float h, k;
        float radiusStart, radiusEnd;
        int counter;

        public Circle(Point2D location, float radius)
        {
            Points = new Point2D[(int)(radius * 201)];
            h = location.X;
            k = location.Y;
            radiusStart = h - radius;
            radiusEnd = h + radius;

            for (float i = radiusStart; i <= radiusEnd; i++)
            {
                Points[counter].X = i;
                Points[counter].Y = (float)(Math.Sqrt((radius * radius) - ((i - h) * (i - h))) + k);
                Points[counter + ((int)(radius * 100))].X = i;
                Points[counter + ((int)(radius * 100))].Y = (Points[counter].Y * -1);
                counter++;
            }

            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Adrian Collado

Comment: have you tried to debug the value?

Comment: You should really think again about this code.

Comment: Where is the counter value in the loop? You have assigned counter as int but without any value.

Comment: @Hoque: `counter` is a member and a value type. The CLR initializes it to zero.

Comment: @Adrian You should un-edit your code to put the error back in so that others can learn from the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen bizarre behavior with: `i = i++`

Try changing `for (float i = radiusStart; i <= radiusEnd; i = i++)` to just use `i++` instead of `i = i++`.

Even if it doesn't fix your issue, it's much better form.

Comment: I must have accidentally typed i = before.. Thanks for noticing it!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the increment step of your for loop: `i = i++`.  It should just be `i++` or `++i`.

`i++` increments i and returns its previous value, which you are then assigning back to i again.  Therefore, i actually ends up with the same value in every iteration of the loop, so it is never greater than radiusEnd, and the loop never terminates (until counter exceeds the upper bound of the array and you get an out of range exception).

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that "counter" is not initialized before you get in your loop, try initializing it to 0 before?

Comment: `counter` is a member, guaranteed to be zero by the CLR.

Comment: Matthew is right. Still good practice, but it's not the issue here.